# Rails send_data with oracle enhanced adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord

I am having an issue retrieving an image that is stored as a blob in a legacy oracle database. When I go to `http://server/images/id/type` I receive a `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error.

I have the following setup:

**GemFile**

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
gem 'ruby-oci8'
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."IMAGE_TABLE" 
(   "IMG_TYPE_SEQ_NO" NUMBER(12,0), 
"IMG_TYPE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
"IMG_DESC" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE), 
"IMG_LENGTH" NUMBER, 
"IMG_BLOB" BLOB
);
```

**Model**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name = 'schema.image_table'

def self.image_by_id_and_type(id, type)
  where(
    'img_type_seq_no = :id and img_type = :type',
     id: id, type: type
  )
end
```

**Controller**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

  def show_image
    @image = Image.image_by_id_and_type(params[:id], params[:type])
    send_data @image[:img_blob], type: 'image/gif', disposition: 'inline'
  end

end
```

I have tried using `send_data @image.img_blob` and get a `undefined method` error with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Chris

**Update:**

I wonder if there is an issue of type conversion. The blob image was persisted via a java swing application that converted it to a java byte array. Could this be the issue? If so, how do I convert a java byte array into something send_data can understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@image = Image.image_by_id_and_type(params[:id], params[:type])
```

is returning an ActiveRecord::Relation object, so in order to get the actual value from it, I had to call `first`.

```
send_data @image.first[:img_blob], type: 'image/gif', disposition: 'inline'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess. Please try with

```
def show_image
    @image = GiftCardImage.image_by_id_and_type(params[:id].to_i, params[:type])
    send_data @image[:img_blob], type: 'image/gif', disposition: 'inline'
end
```

In your model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name = 'schema.image_table'

def self.image_by_id_and_type(id, type)
  where("img_type_seq_no = ? and img_type = ?", id, type)
end
```

Comment: I modified the examples above to remove domain specific names that may have caused confusion.  I missed them when I was trying to generify it.<br/><br/>Your suggestion, while cleaner looking, did not work.  I am getting the same error message.